# Split a regex matched string with commas?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex patters which does altering of the string being matched..

```
var output = Regex.Replace(entity.NamingPattern, @"\[(?<token>.+?)\]|(?<word>[^\[\]])", (match) =>
                    {
                        var wordMatch = match.Groups["word"];
                        if (wordMatch.Success) return $"'{wordMatch.Value}'";
                        return "new."+match.Groups["token"].Value;
                    });
```

but is also possible to ensure that all words and tokens that being matched are separated with a comma?

So something like this

```
(something[tester]somethi[worker]some[i]sadas,
```

is returned as this

```
'(','s','o','m','e','t','h','i','n','g','new.tester','s','o','m','e','t','h','i','new.worker','s','o','m','e','new.i','s','a','d','a','s',','
```

Word matches on each character and token matches with the content each square brackets, and remove the the brackets. but how i join the I am not sure about that?

Comment: Do you mean repeating the character class 1+ times excluding the comma? `\[(?<token>.+?)\]|(?<word>[^\[\],]+)` Then you could get the group2 value and join them with a comma https://regex101.com/r/blMauH/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird the last character should also be included.. it not only numbers but also symbols

Comment: Why is `[i]` not returned as `new.i`?

Comment: Without adding it to the character class `\[(?<token>[^[\]]*)\]|(?<word>[^[\]]+)` https://regex101.com/r/W1UbOG/1

Comment: @Nick indeed it should have been added.

Comment: Perhaps I don't fully understand the question. I thought you wanted to match the whole words instead of separate characters and then join them with a comma. Right now your match looks like this https://regex101.com/r/2ssPMd/1 Do you mean adding a comma after all group 2 values?

Comment: combining into a string rather a char fine.. 
I just want to add a comma between each `token,word` pair and `word,token` pair not sure whether the order should be distinct like that @Thefourthbird

Comment: @kafka You could add it and trim the comma at the end https://ideone.com/qj3fJr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a comma after the *word* group and add surrounding single quotes and a comma for the *token* group.

At the final result, trim the comma at the end of *output* using [TrimEnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimend?view=netcore-3.1)

The non greedy dot `.*?` in the pattern could also be a negated character class `[^[\]]*`

*Pattern*

```
\[(?<token>[^[\]]*)\]|(?<word>[^[\]])
```

[.Net regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b%28%3f%3ctoken%3e%5b%5e%5b%5c%5d%5d*%29%5c%5d%7c%28%3f%3cword%3e%5b%5e%5b%5c%5d%5d%29&i=%28something%5btester%5dsomethi%5bworker%5dsome%5bi%5dsadas%2c)

*Example code*

```
var s  = "(something[tester]somethi[worker]some[i]sadas,";
var output = Regex.Replace(s, @"\[(?<token>[^[\]]*)\]|(?<word>[^[\]])", (match) =>
{
    var wordMatch = match.Groups["word"];
    if (wordMatch.Success) return $"'{wordMatch.Value}',";
    return "'new."+match.Groups["token"].Value+"',";
});
Console.WriteLine(output.TrimEnd(','));
```

*Output*

```
'(','s','o','m','e','t','h','i','n','g','new.tester','s','o','m','e','t','h','i','new.worker','s','o','m','e','new.i','s','a','d','a','s',','
```